# What is best way to execute a Ruby program from a Ruby program?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, eval

I would like to do something like this from a Ruby script, within a loop:

1. Write a file a.rb (which changes each iteration)
2. execute system(ruby 'a.rb')
3. a.rb writes a string with results to a file 'results'
4. a.rb finishes and Ruby returns 'true' (assuming no errors)
5. the calling script reads the file 'results' and takes action.

I expect there are many better ways of doing this. For example, instead of step #2-#5 could I
simply load 'a.rb' (within the loop) and invoke one one of its methods?  Is there a better way by using eval() or something else? (Gaining an understanding of metaprogramming is on my Ruby to-do list.)

Comment: Related question: [Running another ruby script from a ruby script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635108/running-another-ruby-script-from-a-ruby-script)

Comment: Why do you need `a.rb` at all? Why don't you have your main script write `results` file itself? Where does the code you are writing to `a.rb` come from? Does it have to be a string, or it may be code of your main script?

Comment: Thank you, Mladen.  Sorry for taking so long to get back.  The main program is constructing Ruby programs (in a loop), which it stores in an array of strings (or one long string).  It then needs to direct Ruby to run each of these programs.  The results file was simply a brute force way for each of the constructed programs to send its results back to the main program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `eval` is probably the right solution for dynamically-generated code; that's what it's designed for.  Instead of creating `a.rb` at all, just `eval('some-code-that-would-be-in-a.rb')`.

Comment: Wow, that was fast!  Borealid, do you mean eval's argument is a single string containing all the code, with \n at the end of each line of code? I would expect to have the code in an array of strings, though I could of course convert that to a single string.

Comment: @Cary Swoveland: How large a single block passed to `eval` is depends on what you're trying to do - the "granularity" of your task.  Generally, you should try to minimize the number of distinct calls to `eval` you make.

Comment: I see lots of ways to break ruby globally, so use eval only for trusted code.