# Run ruby files through script

Tags: ruby

I want to run all ruby files from specific folder(without using Rake gem)(I'm trying this only for learning purpose). In order to achieve that, I did following:

```
files = Dir[File.join(Dir.pwd, "tests/*.rb")]

files.each do |file|
  ruby file
end
```

when I run above script, it throw an error:

```
run.rb:13:in `block in <main>': undefined method `ruby' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

I've ruby installed on my machine. Please suggest change in my code to work it.

Comment: Possibly already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2636767/877472)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `ruby` method inside ruby programs.
You're using ruby in your terminal because that's the name of the executable, not the name of a function.

You can use `require` to do what you're trying to achieve.

```
files = Dir[File.join(Dir.pwd, "tests/*.rb")]

files.each do |file|
  require file
end
```

Comment: Thanks Damien MATHIEU! I'll accept answer once I'm allowed to.