# How to run multiple ruby scripts?

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to call a ruby script `a` within another ruby script `b`? I have a ruby script which performs the website login (`login.rb`) and another script `order_create.rb`. I want to call `login.rb` first and then execute `order_create.rb` next. Please suggest.
Order_Created.rb:-

```
@@order_data = YAML.load(File.open'C:\Users\order_details.yaml')                                                        def fill_order_form(order_data)
   fill_in 'Firstname', :with => order_data['firstname']
   fill_in 'Lastname', :with => order_data['lastname']
   fill_in 'ZIP', :with => order_data['zip']
   click_button 'Continue' 

   end
```

order_detail.yaml :-

```
firstname: "Order"
lastname: "Test"
zip: "90341"
```

login.rb:-

```
require './order_create.rb'
def login
    #login code here
     fill_order_form(@@order_data)
end

Error on running login.rb :-  undefined method `fill_order_form' for #<#<Class:0x3e344e0>:0x4248ba0>
```

Comment: This depends on what you mean by "call". `require` will execute the script in the current Ruby process, `system` will open a new process which you can run the script with (and provide process-level arguments to), `Open3` will let you open a new process to execute the script which you can then pipe input and output to/from, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A similar (although different) question already been answered at : [Running another ruby script from a ruby script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635108/running-another-ruby-script-from-a-ruby-script)

You can include the script that you want to call in your script with:

```
require './b.rb' #if b.rb is in the same directory
```

and call it with:

```
b(args)
```

for your example, you can do the following:

**login.rb**

```
require './order_create.rb'
def login
    #login code here
    order_create()
end
```

Assuming that your create_order.rb contains `def create_order()`

Comment: Got this error :---- `require': cannot load such file -- Login.rb (LoadError)

Comment: @Anusha If `create_order.rb` is in the same folder as `login.rb` then you could use `require _relative 'order_create'`. Same with wherever you are requiring `login.rb`

Comment: Thanks all. The above error was removed by using require as follow :-   require './Order_Create.rb'

Comment: @Anusha I will edit this answer to reflect that. Thank you. Please mark it as best answer for anybody else coming here with this issue

Answer (score 0):

Even though you can execute any shell command using backticks or %x

```
`ruby yourscript.rb`
%x(ruby yourscript.rb)
```

In this case it isn't good idea, since you have conventional ways of solving this, create third script, say `login_and_order.rb` and put following code inside:

```
require_relative 'login.rb'
require_relative 'order_create.rb'

# run your methods from both scripts in sequence you need
# or if they are just set of commands, nothing else needed
```

Comment: Thanks! . I am able to call a script order_create.rb within another ruby script (login.rb) now . But unable to call the method defined in order_create.rb.   Error Received :- undefined local variable or method `order_data'.                                                                                         Order_Created.rb is like this :-  
@@order_data = YAML.load(File.open'C:\Users\order_details.yaml')                                                                        
def fill_order_form(order_data)
(Have defined all fields in yaml file)
Can u please suggest how to handle this.

Comment: @Anusha so you call it like `order_data`? But `@@order_data` isn't a method, it's class variable(even though I am unable to understand why do you use it outside of the class)

Comment: I am calling it as fill_order_form(order_data) in login.rb . fill_order_form(order_data) is defined in create_order.rb.

Comment: Order_Data has file path of yaml file which has all values to fill the form and create order.          My apologizes for confusion . i am new to Ruby. and trying hard to get thru . Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @Anusha can you just edit your question to show relevant parts from both scripts? From now, I see that you define `@@order_data =`, so you should call `fill_order_form(@@order_data)` accordingly

Comment: Just updated the question with code snippets and error received.

Comment: Can someone pls suggest on this issue.